# Import Backed-up DB from .file format into SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I received a .file which I need to import into my Local SQL Server Express 2014.

I can't find out how to import this file format.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the solution:

I changed file format to .bak and then restored DataBase. It worked for me.